# Redirecting Output of 2nd exe to a text file

Tags: .net

I have a console application called configure.exe it internally launches calls to another console application called setup.exe.
When I want to configure with setup I would use it like

```
C:\> configure fresh
```

i.e. the configure.exe reads various parameters and when I pass fresh, it internally launches that setup.exe in order to do some cleanup. The result of setup.exe is displayed over console.
Everything works perfectly fine. But when I want to redirect the result to a text file like following

```
C:\> configure fresh > out.txt
```

It is simply blank. Possibly because it is the setup.exe not configure.exe who is dumping the output to console. Is there a way to redirect the output to text file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ProcessStartInfo class, especially the property [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/Error is important in this context. If set to true, you can access the output in the process' [StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) stream.
You can read the output from the stream and write it to a file.

Comment: At this moment the code is frozen and I am not allowed to make any changes. Do you know any DOS redirection method like instead of using >, >> or something else that could work?